# How to illustrate that

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, intuition

there is $a, n \in \mathbb Z^{+}$ and prime number $p$, with relationship: $$p|a^{n}$$

It's straight forward that $p|a$, but I can't find a proper illustration of it.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to prove. Why not let $a = p$, then $p \mid p^n$ for every $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$?

Comment: Do you mean that you cannot find a formal *proof* of it?

Comment: I added the *intuition* because my interpretation of the question was that is what the OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

If $p$ does not divide $a$ then it does not divide $a^n$ which conclude the result.

Comment: This is the simplest and in my opinion the best way to think about it. This is considering the prime factorisation of $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to the two other answers given, we can use the property that $p$ is prime to directly show this, without reference to the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Note that we begin with $p | (a a^{n-1})$. Since $p$ is prime, this implies that $p | a$ or $p | a^{n-1}$. In the former case, we're done. Otherwise, repeat with $p | a^{n-1}$. A simple inductive argument completes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite $a$ as the product of its prime factors:

- $a=\prod\limits_{i=1}^k{p_i}^{m}$
- $p|a^n \implies p\in\{p_1,\dots,p_k\} \implies p|a$

Answer (score 0):

Write: $a^n = a^n - a + a$. We know from Fermat's little theorem that: $p|a^n - a$, and $p|a^n$. It follows that $p|(a^n - (a^n - a))$, or $p|a$.

Comment: We know from Fermat's Theorem that $p$ divides $a^p-a$.

Comment: Not so good. It means the argument is incomplete.

Comment: If $p|A$, and $p|B$, then $p| (A-B)$.

Comment: Yes, that is true. And if it had been proved above that $p$ divides $a^n-a$, then it would follow that $p$ divides $a$. However, the fact that $p$ divides $a^n-a$ has not been proved. If $n=p$, then yes, the divisibility follows from Fermat's Theorem. But $n$ is not necessarily equal to $p$.

Comment: oh yeah, i just found out.Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you know about rings and ideals, you should use this to illustrate this fact.

(you may think, that this is abstract and therefore the wrong way, but believe me, here it will support your intuition)

So you know that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a prinicpal ideal domain. We can look at the ideals generated by $a$ and $p$. We know that in our ring, the prime ideals are precisely the maximal ideals. Therefore if the two ideals intersect, which they do since $(0)\neq(a^n)\subset (p)\cap (a)$, it holds that $(a)\subset (p)$. So as soon as an integer element "touches" a prime ideal, all multiples and roots (if they lie in $\mathbb{Z}$) are divisible by the prime spanning this ideal. (the latter fact with the roots uses that it is a pid, the other fact is obviously always true, but stresses what I want to say)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think this is not a good approach as it makes the question "harder".

Comment: I appreciate your comment, but I am aware of this problem, as I stated in the beginning of this answer. The intention is nevertheless, that I believe this to give a good insight, firstly into the question and secondly into abstract mathematics helping intuition.

I assumed the OP to know some facts about rings (since he tagged his question with elementary number theory), and wanted him to use this knowledge to achieve intuition.

This answer only uses the absolutely most basic facts in this topic! One should give it a try